# What does the full research tree look like?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I find myself constantly wishing I had some idea what the research tree looked like. For example, if I want to unlock plasma weapons, do I have to go down the laser weapon path first to unlock it, or am I going in completely in the wrong direction?If I want to get a satellite nexus, what do I need for it? How do I get this stealth armor I've heard about?

I have so many questions like this, and some sort of research tree with related manufacturing items would be of immense help.

Comment: I did just find [this article](http://segmentnext.com/2012/10/09/xcom-enemy-unknown-research-guide-xenobiology-engineering-and-weapon-manufacturing/) which presents the research information and then some. Less tree-like than I thought, with much research dependent on just finding certain materials. Haven't stuck it in an answer yet though because I hate just leaving a link, but I also don't want to do a straight up copy & paste. There's got to be a better way of presenting this information.

Comment: best way is to make a flow diagram if possible.  could be messy though...  nice find however

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is an alternative research tree that you might find userful

http://www.xdude.com/images/xcom-enemy-unknown-2012-tech-tree-research-chart.png

[image]

Comment: Agent86's was very good and much appreciated, but I'm moving the accepted answer to this one because I think it better captures some of the other in-game requirements.

Answer (score 58):

Here's a chart, with neat colors:
[image: current version 2.2]

(Click to expand)

Previous versions:

- [Click for version 2.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxC2N.gif)
- [Click for version 2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGLEJ.gif)
- [Click for version 1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsbCG.gif)

This is only from a couple of sources, ([here](http://www.ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=Research_(EU2012)) and [here](http://segmentnext.com/2012/10/09/xcom-enemy-unknown-research-guide-xenobiology-engineering-and-weapon-manufacturing/)) so it could probably use some verification.  Reddit [provided some input](http://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/11hymi/xcom_eu_tech_tree/) as well.  Feedback is welcome.

Comment: There is an error in version 2.1 - Weapon Fragements or Alien Materials is a prereq to "experitmental warfare". Beam weapons unlocks "Laser Pistol (g) and Laser Rifle (g)

Comment: also - there is some 'prereuq' to Beam Weapons - but I'm not sure what it is yet. I started a new game on 'easy', researched ONLY  Weapon Fragments, and I was not able to get Beam Weapons. I then researched Alloys and Experimental Warfare - and I was still not able to research Beam Weapons...

Comment: for "Beam weapons" - I just did a small 'downed' ufo ship - and that unlocked beam weapons

Comment: Yeah, several (or all) techs seem require you get to a certain point in the game - I didn't get Carapace Armour unlocked for research until I'd seen an Outsider (this may be a coincidence).

Comment: Carapace Armor's unlocked pretty early.  I think the "Downed UFO" is a key event, although it's a bit hard to determine what exactly it gates.

Comment: @agent86 Alloys. As soon as you have them, Beam Weapons become available after Weapon Fragments. Carapace Armor is the same boat.