# Are there any benefits to capturing live zombies?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Is it possible to capture a zombie live? Is there any benefit to doing so? I was really hoping that I could rescue some of my dead soldiers by capturing them alive as zombies. It's probably not how it works, but I'm curious what the benefits of capturing zombies are.

Comment: Would have been so cool if you could.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't capture a zombie, chryssalid, or any of the robots (sectopod, drone, and cyberdisc) alive.  Even if you close to Arc Thrower range, you won't be able to use it on them.  (Well, the drones you can 'reprogram' using the arc thrower, with the right foundry project, but you can't "capture" them per se)

There's no interrogation of these types of enemies possible.  If your soldier gets zombified, that's it - they're gone.

Comment: You can check what you can and can't use the arc thrower on by selecting a soldier with it equipped and then looking for the blue circle around the enemy.

Comment: You can also check the [tech tree](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/87659/13845) - if there's no 'interrogation' bonus, you can't capture them alive.  Also, there's no autopsy for zombified humans either...