# What does Enemy Within research tree looks like?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I have problems getting Edison achievement so is there any shiny diagrams like in [What does the full research tree look like?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87637/what-does-the-full-research-tree-look-like) for an expansion?

Answer (score 3):

I believe there are no additional research items other than single MELD research and autopsies for Mechtoid and Seeker. But the results of the research are expanded and there are multiple new foundry items.

Comment: Don't forget all the Foundry projects and Research for your MEC troopers like Jellied Elyrium for the flamethrower, shaped armour, advanced servos

Comment: There are lots of changes - lots of new results of research, and lots of new foundry projects. The full research tree is more than what is accessed from the Research menu :-)

Comment: i believe the eddison achievement also relates to the slingshot expansion, aka also have to reasearch the new items that come from those missions to get the achievement