# What is the full research tree?

Tags: xenonauts

In a similiar vein to [What does the full research tree look like?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87637/what-does-the-full-research-tree-look-like) for XCOM: Enemy Unkown, I'd like to have an image of the full research tree for Xenonauts. Ideally I'd want it to outline both research requirements as well as event requirements  like in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/94136/8350). It would be extremely helpful in prioritizing my research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This image may be correct

[image: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/displayimageformodaldialog/?imageurl=http://cloud-4.steampowered.com/ugc/23960773087379955/7EDD2DC51F4F600E717941C1681C712740002811/]

From:
http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=261562486&insideModal=1

Comment: I've played through most of the game now, and this is accurate in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played the game to verify, but this looks promising:[image]

I found it [here](http://xenonauts.wikia.com/wiki/Tech_Trees).

Comment: I believe this is not accurate. For instance I don't see High Speed Interceptor on there.