# What does the full research tree look like for XCOM 2?

Tags: xcom-2

In the same vein as this [XCOM:EU question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87637/what-does-the-full-research-tree-look-like), I'd like to know which autopsies need to be performed first in order to get the tech needed to get better equipment down the road.  This would help me plan out when and where I need to get enemies in order to advance my soldier's techs.

What is the full research tree for XCOM 2?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This tech tree, [compiled and created by MenhirMike](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/44qkn9/xcom_2_tech_tree_wip_possible_spoilers/), shows which reseearch as well as building facilities need to be have completed before getting a certain piece of tech. The latest update fixes a lot of the incorrect research requirements and also adds the different requirements needed across all difficulties.

[image]

The color codes are as listed:

- **Black**: Missions, actions or item drops in the game
- **Red**: Research
- **Purple**: Proving Grounds projects
- **Blue**: Items
- **Green**: Buildings
- **Orange**: Stuff related to the Main Quest
- Stuff marked **(r)** is repeatable

Comment: The tree is mostly complete for all the items. Stuff currently (as of Version 3) missing: Main Quest (e.g., Encrypted Codex Data is a dead end even though it's a requirement for the next story mission), Black Market (there is something else apart from time for it to show up) and a better layout. But the stuff people are usually interested in should all be complete and useful to plan out how to kick some Alien butt :)

Comment: Update: The resource numbers (how much supply etc.) are inaccurate, some even on Rookie. I found an .ini file that tweaks them, and makes them different per difficulty for some items. The overall path/prerequisites are correct, just the numbers are not. I'll update them sometime today.

Comment: So, just from looking at that tree, I think you have the descriptions for Orange and Purple switched. As there are a number of orange things off the main quest line, and all the purple things are both required in the tree that leads to the final mission box, and labeled as (item) or (item drop).