# How does the full research tree and resistance orders look like for XCOM 2: War of the Chosen?

Tags: xcom-2, xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

In the same vein as this [XCOM 2 question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/254409/what-does-the-full-research-tree-look-like-for-xcom-2), I'd like to see the research graph. plus a list of the breakthroughs.

Ideally also a list of resistance orders as well.

Comment: If we're adding to the wish list, full cost breakdowns for facilities/items.  (Don't sell your six ADVENT Trooper corpses before building the first armor upgrade...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the research tree, including the breakthroughs, made (I assume) by user *peddroelm* on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/9o2xq2/is_there_an_uptodate_wotc_tech_tree/). 

On the linked page, *peddroelm* gives a link ([direct](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uxDOqnYsLdfYJhhiNAarOxp18gfOW4jc/view?usp=sharing)) to the source `.graphml` file as well, so you can change the layout to your liking.

[image: Research Tree for X-Com 2: War of the Chosen]